# Database query vs. programming language to check for occurence in data

Tags: sqlite

I have a database with first names and last names.
I select some of them, not all.
I want to show the last name with one exception, when the last name is the same for two people in the current selection, prepend the initial of the first name followed by full-stop space. (`G.`)

The app is running on a mobile device so I'm worried that looping through data and comparing each name with all the other names (for inside for) is too resource costly.

Is it possible to check this in the query and do a `case` statement where I concatenate substr of first name with `.`?

How should I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following SQL queries show how to do achieve this.

```
select firstname, lastname from employee;
 firstname | lastname 
-----------+----------
 Fred      | Bloggs
 Joe       | Citizen
 Bill      | Citizen
 Andrew    | Smith


select case when (select count(*) from employee E where E.Lastname=E2.Lastname) > 1 then substr(firstname, 1, 1) || '. ' else '' end || lastname from employee E2;
  ?column?  
------------
 Bloggs
 J. Citizen
 B. Citizen
 Smith
```

It would be helpful to have an index on the lastname column so that the sub-query is more efficient.

Comment: MU: You're saying that it might be faster to loop through all received data in the programming language?

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find this less efficient and possibly more difficult to do in SQL, which doesn't provide any tools for examining neighboring rows: you'd have to perform a subquery, or a join on every row in order to see whether there is some other row with the same last name.

As long as you are only processing a page of results at a time (which you did say), and sorting by last name, then you can handle this by storing a single row and "looking ahead" to the next row for a duplicate last name.  This shouldn't require much memory in the client.  However, you should probably request one more result than you want to display, in order to be sure the first result on the next page doesn't share the same last name as the last on this page.